# Drying up multiples scopes with simialar queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am noticing a trend with my scopes and trying to figure out how to make it dry

```
scope :newest, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
scope :top_sold, -> { order('qty_sold DESC') }
scope :most_viewed, -> { order('qty_viewed DESC') }
scope :most_downloaded, -> { order('qty_download DESC') }
scope :most_favorited, -> { order('qty_favorited DESC') }
```

I would like to pass in the column I want sorted so that I can call it on Photo. I tried  this, but running into problems

```
scope :sort_photos, -> type { order('type DESC') }
Photo.sort_photos('qty_download')
```

Am I on the right path or is there a smarter way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `type` as a scope parameter and use that in `order` clause with string interpolation:

```
scope :sort_photos,->(type) { order("#{type} DESC") }
```

Then do:

```
Photo.sort_photos('qty_download')
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`order`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) method takes a String or a Hash. So instead of `order('created_at DESC')` you can do `order(created_at: :desc)`, for example. So, to accomplish what you want, it's as simple as changing the key to your `type` variable:

```
scope :sort_photos, -> type { order(type => :desc) }
```

I would also recommend using a sentinel for your `order` scopes such as `by_`. So that the scope `by_sort_photos` doesn't get overridden by definition of a `sort_photos` method or assoication later.

Finally, it's good to have a public interface full of methods, as opposed to requiring knowledge of the class attributes and passing those attribute names into a public interface method. So I'd keep the many different scopes that you have, but perhaps have them all refer to the one, general scope as we've defined here. So:

```
scope :newest, -> { by_most_recent_type('created_at') }
scope :top_sold, -> { by_most_recent_type('qty_sold') }

scope :by_most_recent_type, -> type { order(type => :desc) }
```